# Divergence of magnetic field (mathematically)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

How is the divergence zero for a magnetic field? (I understand this intuitively, I need math.)

Comment: What do you mean by: *I need math*? The math is simply divergence equal to zero! Do you mean that you want a *proof* of this?

Comment: How do you understand it intuitively?

Comment: It is more like an axiom coming from observation: there are no magnetic monopoles in electromagnetism since we don't observe them. Therefore we require $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic field at a distance $r$ produced due to current density $\vec{J}$ confined in volume $\mathcal{V}$ is given by Biot-Savart law as -
$$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_\mathcal{V}\frac{\vec{J}\times\hat{r}}{r^2}d\tau$$
We will calculate the surface integral of the vector field $\vec{B}$ over a spherical surface containing the current source.
$$\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{a} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\vec{J}\times\hat{r}}{r^2}\cdot r^2\ \sin(\theta)\ d\phi\ d\theta\ \hat{r}d\tau$$
Since, $\vec{J}\times\hat{r}$ and $\hat{r}$ are orthogonal so -
$$\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{a} = 0$$
Invoking the Fundamental theorem of gradient-
$$\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{a} = \int\nabla\cdot\vec{B}\ d\tau$$
or,$$\int\nabla\cdot\vec{B}\ d\tau = 0$$
Since this is true for any arbitrary volume so -
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{B} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf {B} = \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} = 0$$